# Promise handling not working, on Angular Log In

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, aws-amplify

I am trying to set a global log in variable in my Angular 13 application.

I am using AWS amplify and can successfully log in, but once that promise is complete, I want to set the `isLoggedIn` variable to true to use throughout my application but it is not being set.

Here is the function I am calling in my authService:

```
  login(usernameOrEmail: string, password: string): Promise<AuthUser> {
    return this.awsService.login(usernameOrEmail, password).then(cognitoUser => this.cognitoUser = cognitoUser).finally(()=>this.setIsLoggedIn(true)) //<-- would like to call this function after the previous 'then'
  }

   // this function never gets called
   public setIsLoggedIn(loggedin: boolean):any{
     this.isLoggedSubject.next(loggedin);
   }
```

And here is the login function/Promise in my AWS service that I am calling:

```
  async login(usernameOrEmail: string, password: string): Promise<AuthUser> {
    const cognitoUser = await Auth.signIn(
      usernameOrEmail.toLowerCase(),
      password
    ).catch((error) => {
      //handle error
    });

    return cognitoUser;
  }
```

What can I change/do so that I can set my cognitoUser properly AND set `isLoggedIn` to true?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple lines in your first `then()` scope

```
return this.awsService.login(usernameOrEmail, password)
                      .then(cognitoUser => { 
                            this.cognitoUser = cognitoUser;
                            this.setIsLoggedIn(true)
                      })
```